# How to get the post id from a permalink?

Tags: permalinks, functions, posts, urls

How can I get the post id from a permalink like "http://localhost/wordpress/animals/cat" in functions.php, I have tried url_to_postid() and get_page_by_path() but none seem to work.

Comment: Is *"animals"* a custom post type?

Comment: yes it is a custom post type

Comment: As wordpress can visit that url, it obviously knows how to do the permalinks to post id conversion, I need to do this as a function so that I can get the id other pages than the one I'm currently visiting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi **@Tirithen:**

Have you tried *(which assumes your custom post type is `'animal'` and not `'animals'`):*

```
$post = get_page_by_path('cat',OBJECT,'animal');
```

Comment: Yes, it's working fine now, I did not understand the syntax before. Thanks :-)

Comment: @Tirithen - Glad I could help!